# Group by SQL questions

Tags: sql, group

This is the table look that I have:

```
   apt     block   student     startday       endday        movein   moveout
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------   
   160     1        Adam     2023-06-05    2023-06-09       yes 
   160     1        Adam     2023-06-11    2023-06-16                yes
   160     2        Adam     2023-07-10    2023-07-16       yes
   160     2        Adam     2023-07-17    2023-07-22      
   160     2        Adam     2023-07-25    2023-07-30                yes
   160     3        Adam     2023-08-10    2023-07-16       yes
   160     4        Adam     2023-08-17    2023-08-30
   160     5        Adam     2023-09-10    2023-09-16                yes
```

I need this output:

```
  apt   block   student     inDate           OutDate
  ------------------------------------------------------
  160   1        Adam     2023-06-05         2023-06-16 
  160   2        Adam     2023-07-10         2023-07-30  
  160   3        Adam     2023-08-10         2023-09-16 
  160   4        Adam     2023-08-10         2023-09-16 
  160   5        Adam     2023-08-10         2023-09-16
```

I was using this code but it doesn't pull block 4.

```
select 
    apt, block, student, 
    max(case when ch.[movein] = 'yes' then ch.[Startday] end) as inDate,
    max(case when ch.[moveout] = 'yes' then ch.[endday] end) as OutDate
from 
    table ch
where 
    apt = '160'
group by 
    apt, student, block
```

I tried the code I mentioned, but it returns an incorrect output.

Comment: Why not just `min(ch.movein), max(ch.moveout)`

Comment: OK, changed to Min . still same output

Comment: Can you describe the logic here a bit more? Blocks 1 and 2 make sense. But why exactly is 2023-08-16 the OutDate for block 3? Is it because 2023-08-16 is the next move out record for Adam and Apartment (regardless of block)?

Comment: Also, what DBMS are you using (SQL Server, Oracle, etc...)?

Comment: the purpose is pull the same student, same apartment, for each blocks movein date and moveout date. For block 4 issue, the student move in while he was in block3, and stayed until end of the block5. So when i pull block4 data i need to see block3 movein date and block5 moveout date

Comment: I just realized how complicated your ask is and I don't think it's do able via one statement.  It will need to be broken out into two-three separate blocks.

Comment: yes, its hard to make it with one command. how to broken up

Comment: @QuestionGuyBob I'm up to 3 CTEs and two different subselects. It really is a horrible design. This table should be three columns with two keys back to a LUT and a date. Its doing way too much and making his problem harder to solve.

Comment: @ayla How do you get a moveIn date for Block 4 that is after the actual date in block 4? What is the business logic there that points it to two different blocks. How does the move in date go into the future past the date there and what rules do you apply to select for it? I can give you the bulk of what you need but you have to handle the stuff for block 4. Is your data above incorrect and your desired output should use 7/10/23 instead of 8/10/23 for the Block 4 In Date?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c710aa/4/0 this sqlfiddle gives the same output as above, however I don't believe that your expected output is correct and with limited data and expected output to work with its anyones guess. Edited my fiddle to account for your data changes in your OP.

Comment: need more info, I do see block=4,   see: https://dbfiddle.uk/slgkpwWf.    Also _expected_ output is missing, or should we **guess** what you expect?

Comment: The question was closed while I was posting an answer. See [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Mv5oAHi5yc2k42hDMkanu/0) for an answer to your question. It's slightly ugly but not too bad. Might be able to modify and remove the CTE somehow, but I need to run to an appointment.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Adjusted query here to cover your updated requirements. SqlFiddle link has also been adjusted for your edited OP dataset/output requirements.

That said, the table structure you are using here unnecessarily complicates things. Are there situations where they would ever both be yes? what are the options allowed other than yes and null? Could it be `No`, `Fish`, `Tree`, or `Bird`? You should consider using a bit if it is one of two things or a lookuptable with a key to reference why the entry was added in a single column.
All of that repeated data for apt, block student? Why not make that its own relationship table and key back to it? the two different dates should probably be removed and one date column used in conjunction with the first LUT key. A solution to your question is below.

Simply put, there are bigger issues here than simply your query wasn't working.

```
DECLARE @apt int = 160;
WITH AptBlockStudents As (
  SELECT DISTINCT
     apt 
    ,block 
    ,student 
  FROM t1
  ),
MoveIns AS (
  SELECT 
     apt 
    ,block 
    ,student 
    ,MIN(ch.[Startday]) AS inDate
  FROM t1 AS ch
  WHERE apt= 160 AND moveIn = 'Yes'
  GROUP BY apt, student, block
),
MoveOuts AS (
   SELECT 
     apt 
    ,block 
    ,student 
    ,MAX(ch.[endday]) AS OutDate
  FROM t1 AS ch
  WHERE apt= 160 AND moveOut = 'Yes'
  GROUP BY apt, student, block
  )
  SELECT 
    ABS.Apt,
    ABS.Block,
    ABS.Student,
    COALESCE(MoveIns.InDate,(
      SELECT TOP 1 StartDay
      FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      MoveIns AS M ON T1.apt = M.Apt
      AND T1.Student = M.Student
      WHERE T1.MoveIn = 'Yes' 
        AND T1.StartDay <= M.InDate
      ORDER BY T1.StartDay DESC
    )) AS InDate,
    COALESCE(MoveOuts.OutDate,(
     SELECT TOP 1 EndDay
      FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      MoveOuts AS M ON T1.apt = M.Apt
      AND T1.Student = M.Student
      WHERE T1.MoveOut = 'Yes'
        AND T1.EndDay >= M.OutDate
      ORDER BY T1.EndDay DESC
    )) AS OutDate
  FROM AptBlockStudents AS ABS LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MoveIns ON MoveIns.apt = ABS.apt 
      AND MoveIns.Block = ABS.Block
      AND MoveIns.Student = ABS.Student LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MoveOuts ON MoveOuts.apt = ABS.apt 
      AND MoveOuts.Block = ABS.Block
      AND MoveOuts.Student = ABS.Student
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c710aa/4/0)

Comment: @alya, ClearlyClueLess answer will get you your output, assuming you aren't required to base your date returns based on only the movein and moveout data having "yes".  If you are required to have them only based on it, you will have "NULL" returns unless you default the NULLs to something.

Comment: Also note: If the data example for Adam (block 2) had a end date of 2023-08-01 instead of 2023-07-22, and you had a requirement of needing a moveout data having yes, the above will report incorrectly.  So, I guess a clarification on what the rule is would help.

Comment: I've adjusted my post to add a query that will account for move in/moveOut having some value if necessary. The real issue here is poor db design.

Comment: this code pulls the same movein dates and same moveout dates in the same block. What i am trying to do is; student move to apartment(movein) in block 3, and moves back (moveout) end of the block 5. When i create my code at the top, block 4 data has issue. student in the apartmen in block 4, and we need to see block movein date as  2023-08-10  , moveout ' 2023-08-16 '. so block3, block4, block5 same indate and outdate. Becaouse i need to see only movein date, and moveout date.